# Bash pipeline with sed and cut extremely slow

Tags: bash, sed, time-complexity, cut

i'm using a pipeline composed by

```
returnedValue=`sed -n -e "$2 p" $1 | cut -c $START-$END`
```

where $1 is a file name, $2 is a particular row in $1 and $START-$END are the initial-ending position in the row.

I need to computate $returnedValue a lot of time and it's extremely slow.

Is there a better way to do that?

Where's the computation complexity in the above instruction?

Thanks,

Luca

Comment: You could use `sed -n "$2{p;q}"` to quit after encountering that line, or `awk "NR==$2{print;quit}"`.

Comment: `sed -n "1{p;q}" filename` returns command garbled

Comment: Are you on a mac/BSD? They don't like the `;`, you need to use `$2$'{p\nq\n}'`, but see my answer first.

Comment: Yeah, they have funny/non-gnu tools too.

Answer (score 1):

According to the benchmarks in [the answers here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47407/11750) (disclaimer: my answer is the accepted one), the fastest way to get that line is going to be

```
returnedValue=`head -n +$2 "$1" | tail -n 1 | cut -c "$START-$END"`
```

The complexity of your original command is O(N), where N is the number of lines in the file, and this is O($2). Additionally, `head` and `tail` are designed solely to pick out certain lines from a file, so they are highly optimized for this task.

Comment: Something miss on tail part? It returns the tail synopsis...
O(n) only if i assume `sed -n -e "$2 p" $1 | cut -c $START-$END` like a constant.

Comment: Looks like solaris doesn't use the `-n` unless you use /usr/xpg4/bin/tail, so just use `tail -1`.

Comment: And I'm not sure the `head` part will work on Solaris, its utilities are pretty basic. Can you use /usr/xpg4/bin/tail and /usr/xpg4/bin/head?

Comment: /usr/xpg4/bin/tail return no errors but /usr/xpg4/bin/head returns No such file or directory

Comment: `returnedValue=head -n +$2 "$1" | /usr/xpg4/bin/tail -n 1 | cut -c "$START-$END"` appears slow like the first form, it could be?